# multiple liner regression using r. syntax for selecting certain values in columns

Tags: r, selection, multiple-regression

I have a data set, I'm trying to preform a multiple `liner regression` on its as follows:

```
 subject_ID adrenlvl stimuli
1           1   2945.7       3
2           2   2074.4       1
3           3   3362.4       3
4           4   3363.9       2
5           5   2079.6       3
6           6   3373.3       1
7           7   3365.8       2
8           8   2369.7       3
9           9   2078.8       2
```

I know, I need to use

`lm(response ~ explanatory_1 + explanatory_2 + … + explanatory_p)`

But for my explanatory variables I'm confused as to how I select them when all three exist in the same column. I need to split the stimuli column into 1,2,3. is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: you want to to look at `library(reshape)` and `?reshape::dcast` It will allow you to transform from your current "long" format to "wide.

Comment: does r come with this on install?

Comment: As Nathan said, you need `library(reshape2)` - you can obtain it by `install.packages("reshape2")`.

Answer (score 0):

ended up installing reshape and tidyr. ended up using tidyr, was much more initiative to use.